# Odeint : system of complex differential equations is possible in c++?

Tags: c++, differential-equations, odeint

I'm trying to integrate a system of 2 complex valued differential equations in c++ using odeint library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <complex>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

 const double sigma = 10.0;
 
 const double gamma = 0.1; 
 const double J12 = 1; 
 const double G = 1; 
 const double eta = 0.01; 
 const double gamma_s = 0.1; 

 const int n = 2; 

 typedef boost::array< complex<double> , n > state_type;
 //typedef runge_kutta4< complex<double> > stepper_type; tried this and 
 //typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< complex<double> > stepper_type; // this but still        many errors 


   void lorenz( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t )
   {
   dxdt[0] =  -0.5*gamma*x[0] 
           - eta * (abs(x[0])*x[0])//
           + G * conj(x[0])
           + J12 * gamma_s * (x[0]+x[1]);

   dxdt[1] =  -0.5*gamma*x[1] 
           - eta * (abs(x[1])*x[1])
           + G * conj(x[1])
           + J12 * gamma_s * (x[0]+x[1]);
   }
```

but I get many errors when compiling. Indeed I get something like :

```
include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta_dopri5.hpp:142:52:
error: no matching function for call to
    'boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations::scale_sum4<std::complex<double>, double,
     double, double>::scale_sum4(double, std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>,
     std::complex<double>)'
142 |                 typename operations_type::template scale_sum4< value_type ,
      time_type , time_type , time_type >( 1.0 , dt*b41 , dt*b42 , dt*b43 ));
```

I also saw that someone had the same problem but with just one complex valued equation : [Do controlled error steppers in boost odeint support complex data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302970/do-controlled-error-steppers-in-boost-odeint-support-complex-data-types)

Is there a way to fix it also with systems if complex valued ode ?

Comment: Should the tempate parameter for the steppers be `state_type`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm not sure, they do like this in some examples like this one  : https://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html

Comment: also adding `typedef runge_kutta4< state_type > stepper_type;` does not change the errors

Comment: The documentation is rather vague, but I think that you need also set the value_type template parameters to complex, I'm not sure if that gets automatically recognized from the state vector type. I thought that the [example with matrix states](https://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/using_matrices_as_state_types.html) would be more helpful as guidance, but the docu is either too minimalist or goes far deeper than reasonable for our purposes.